# Save data from FetchAPI Json to var

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I'm fetching data from API and would like to save the data received in a var that will be used later in another part of the code.

```
var rates = [];
let url = "https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/USD";

fetch(url)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(myJson => {
    rates = myJson.rates
  })


  console.log(rates)
```

I'm confused because the console.log shows an empty array but if I type the name of the variable in the browser debugger it shows the object received from the API.

I would like to fetch the data from the API and save that data in arrays to be later used in other parts of the code.

Comment: Of course? Your code runs `fetch(url)` and _immediately_ moves on to `console.log`. The `then(...)` bits don't kick in until "some time later" once the network call resolves. If you want to console log the rates after the promise chain has finished, you'll need to either log inside your last `then`, or add another `then()` and do your console logging in there.

Comment: `.then(    
    console.log(rates[1])
  )
 `
gives "undefined" in the console.

Comment: yes, because `then` relies on a previous function returning a value. For example: `fetch(...).then(res => res.json()).then(obj => obj.rates).then(rates => console.log(rates)).catch(err => console.error(err));` (note, that example does not _set_ your `rates` variable, of course. It just illustrates `then` chaining)

Comment: `rates` is not an Array, it's a Object Literal. `.then(myJson=> { const rates = myJson.rates; console.log(rates.EUR); })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building up on Mike's answer, the then(...) is **asynchronous**. What this means is that it doesn't execute in sequence with the previous and next statements. Because of this behavior, the browser executes the console.log ( at which time the array is empty which is why you get an empty result) and after the fetch is complete is when you happened to search it in the console (already populated!).

This happens with AJAX calls as well. It is just a part of the asynchronous behavior of JS.

Comment: Ok I'm getting a better understanding of the asynchronous execution. How can I fix this? Or do I put all my code **inside** the `.then()` block?

Comment: Put all your code in a function and call that function from the then block